# Is exponential CDF solvable for $\lambda$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve $F(x,\lambda)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$ for $\lambda$. $F$ and $x$ are known since they come from a risk management exercise of specifying extreme scenarios' impact as a percentile (90%) of the exponential distribution. I arrive at $\lambda =\frac{\ln(1-F)}{x}$ which obviously leads to negative λ.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You get $\lambda = -\ln(1-F)/x$ and since $0 \le F < 1$ and $ x > 0$ your $\lambda$ is positive.